# Flutter Futurebuilder with List does not work

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

I have a Futurebuilder with a Future function that returns a List with image urls from Firebase storage inside.

```
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: getImages(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      //print(snapshot.data);
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        print(snapshot.data[0]);
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 2,//snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              //var downloadUrl = snapshot.data[index];
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                 leading: Image.network(
                     //downloadUrl
                    "https://placehold.it/500x500"
                     , fit: BoxFit.fill),
              );
            });
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
        return Text("No data");
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
  Future<List<String>> getImages() async{
    var showcaseCode = await page.where("userID",isEqualTo:
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get();
    List downloadUrlList = [];
    var showcaseCodeLength = showcaseCode.docs.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < showcaseCodeLength; i++){
      var url = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref()
          .child("showcase_images")
          .child(showcaseCode.docs[i]["showcaseCode"])
          .getDownloadURL();
      await downloadUrlList.add(url);
    }
    print(downloadUrlList);
    return downloadUrlList;
  }
```

When I print the `downloadUrlList` in the `getImages` Future there is the right output with my url list. But if I print the `downloadUrlList`  in the Futurebuilder, I'll get following error:

```
The method '[]' was called on null. 
Receiver: null 
Tried calling: [](0)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello, so can you try using Stream builder, as it is more efficient ?
Like we can directly pass the Firebase instance in the stream and they will render the data dynamically.

Comment: just for test replace `//print(snapshot.data);` with `print(snapshot);`

Comment: When i do `print(snapshot)` i only got this: I/flutter ( 6870): AsyncSnapshot<List<String>>(ConnectionState.done, null, type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<String>>')

Comment: so you have an error `"type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<String>>"` - thats why `data` is `null` - `List downloadUrlList = <String>[]` should help

Comment: @SARAN SURYA I think that won't work with the Firebase storage

Comment: did you try: `List downloadUrlList = <String>[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an answer in this question:

As @pskink comment, using the following codes fixed the issue:

```
List downloadUrlList = <String>[]
```

or

```
List<String> downloadUrlList = []
```